# Python, any() method for data analysis

Tags: python

I'm currently going through the book called python for data analysis.

There's a part about finding outliers and it looks something like this (check the code).

Although it doesn't look hard at first glance it made me realise that I don't really understand python's any function even though it appears to be easy.

Most resources I checked just mention things like "any() is a built-in function in Python 3, to check if any of the items of an iterable 14 is True. It takes one argument, iterable." source (https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/python-any-iterable/19210)

This simple definition I understand by in this example **how is the number 1 an iterable?** I've checked the code and it does somehow require this 1. Also the python documentation only mentions it being an built-in function that takes an argument in the parenthesis which is an iterable. However, there is lacking information of **how any is used as a method like in the example below.**

python documentation for built-in functions:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any

Please could someone enlighten me? (Main parts of the questions have been bolded for clarity)

```
data[(np.abs(data)>0.8).any(1)]
```

Comment: The simple answer is the any in the line of code at the bottom of your question isn’t the built in `any()` function, it’s a numpy any() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the built-in function [any](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) with the numpy function [numpy.any](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html).

They have the same name because do the same thing, but are different functions and require different arguments.
numpy arrays can be multidimensonal, the 1 in your case is the axis on which perform the operation.

If you are confused by the missing iterable, remember that `numpy.any` is a method. The first argument is the object which call the method: `data.any(1)` is equal to `numpy.any(data, 1)`.

Example:

```
>>> data
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7],
       [8, 9]])

>>> data > 4
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]])
```

No axis provided, `any` acts on the full 2D array.

```
>>> (data > 4).any()
True
```

axis = 0: `any` is performed on each column (result is one value per column).

```
>>> (data > 4).any(0)
array([ True,  True])
```

axis = 1: `any` is performed on each row (result is one value per row).

```
>>> (data > 4).any(1)
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True])
```

Comment: All of the answers were beneficial but yours was spot on and directly answers all of the confusion I had, great answer thank you!

Answer (score 4):

That is because the `any` you have here is not the builtin one, but rather the `numpy` one. In you console try:

```
help(any)
```

and

```
help(np.array(1).any)
```

to see the difference. `any` in your case is the axis to check if any value along said axis evaluates to True.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however there is still some confusion after consuting the numpy documentation for any(). In the documentation it seems the input 'a' is put through in as an argument in the parenthesis and not attached as a prefix to the method. Also it doesn't specify anything about the number 1 inside the parenthesis. What does this do?https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html

Comment: @JKong: That's still the wrong `any`. You're using the [`ndarray.any` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any), not `numpy.any`.

Comment: @JKong yup, see what user2357112 said - if you do not use an array object, but `np.any`, you need to supply the array as the first argument.